# Gnome backgroud log in, not change(after change it)

Tags: gnome, login

I try to change the login background picture in Gnome (GNOME Shell 3.14.4 - Ubuntu 15.04), doing this [Thread: Unable to change GDM Login screen background](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189983).

```
copy the image you want to use into the /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme folder
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css

Search for the following section

#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2e3436 url(noise-texture.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;

change the name of the image to your image
set background to repeat or no-repeat

Save the file
logout and your new background is there
```

My image is a .jpg file, Can be this the problem? , any solution for this?
If you need more information, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine (I think I did use a JPG a while ago), however a few notes:

- If you want it to fill the display (unless you are modifying the CSS further), you will need to make the image the same size as the usual display resolution to work properly (unless you want it to tile multiple copies)
- If you make copies of the files you have added/modified, this will  make it easier
- For 3.16+, its fairly complicated (see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197036#p1526363) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image):)

> *Note: Since GNOME 3.16, GNOME Shell themes are now stored binary
>   files (gresource).*
>
> Firstly, you need to extract the existing GNOME Shell theme to a
>   folder in your home directory. You can do this using the following
>   script (`extractgst.sh`)
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> workdir=${HOME}/shell-theme
> if [ ! -d ${workdir}/theme ]; then
>   mkdir -p ${workdir}/theme
> fi
> gst=/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
>
> for r in `gresource list $gst`; do
>         gresource extract $gst $r >$workdir${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/}
> done
> ```
>
> Navigate to the created directory. You should find that the theme
>   files have been extracted to it. Now copy your preferred background
>   image to this directory.
>
> Next, you need to create a file `gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml` in
>   the directory with the following content:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <gresources>
>   <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/shell/theme">
>     <file>calendar-arrow-left.svg</file>
>     <file>calendar-arrow-right.svg</file>
>     <file>calendar-today.svg</file>
>     <file>checkbox-focused.svg</file>
>     <file>checkbox-off-focused.svg</file>
>     <file>checkbox-off.svg</file>
>     <file>checkbox.svg</file>
>     <file>close-window.svg</file>
>     <file>close.svg</file>
>     <file>corner-ripple-ltr.png</file>
>     <file>corner-ripple-rtl.png</file>
>     <file>dash-placeholder.svg</file>
>     <file>filter-selected-ltr.svg</file>
>     <file>filter-selected-rtl.svg</file>
>     <file>gnome-shell.css</file>
>     <file>gnome-shell-high-contrast.css</file>
>     <file>logged-in-indicator.svg</file>
>     <file>filename</file>
>     <file>more-results.svg</file>
>     <file>no-events.svg</file>
>     <file>no-notifications.svg</file>
>     <file>noise-texture.png</file>
>     <file>page-indicator-active.svg</file>
>     <file>page-indicator-inactive.svg</file>
>     <file>page-indicator-checked.svg</file>
>     <file>page-indicator-hover.svg</file>
>     <file>process-working.svg</file>
>     <file>running-indicator.svg</file>
>     <file>source-button-border.svg</file>
>     <file>summary-counter.svg</file>
>     <file>toggle-off-us.svg</file>
>     <file>toggle-off-intl.svg</file>
>     <file>toggle-on-us.svg</file>
>     <file>toggle-on-intl.svg</file>
>     <file>ws-switch-arrow-up.png</file>
>     <file>ws-switch-arrow-down.png</file>
>   </gresource>
> </gresources>
> ```
>
> Replace **filename** with the filename of your background image.
>
> Now, open the gnome-shell.css file in the directory and change the `#lockDialogGroup` definition as follows:
>
> ```
> #lockDialogGroup {
>   background: #2e3436 url(filename);
>   background-size: [WIDTH]px [HEIGHT]px;
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
> }
> ```
>
> Set `background-size` to the resolution that GDM uses, this might not
>   necessarily be the resolution of the image. Again, set **filename** to be the name of the background image.
>
> Finally, compile the theme using the following command:
>
> ```
> $ glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
> ```
>
> Then copy the resulting `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file to the
>   `/usr/share/gnome-shell` directory.
>
> Restart GDM - you should find that it is using your preferred
>   background image

Answer (score -4):

well frankly speaking, since "noise-texture.png" is in ".png" format, it`s prefered that you use a background with the same format to evade other sys issues.

best guess is try converting your favorate .jpg to a .png ---> peace out ;)